# Selenium: -browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile and savetodisk is not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a critical issue over here.
Please find my scenario below:

1. login
2. click on a link
3. after the click, a new tab opens

I have switched the focus to the new opened tab with the following code

```
ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(1));
```

The issue is that when I try to click on an excel download link on the newly opened tab, the "Open with" popup is appearing and my automation fails. Even after adding the following preference

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
"text/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
"text/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

Please, can you suggest a feasible solution as soon as possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please manually set these preferences in your firefox's(**about:config**) section, visit the application, click the link and see if the file gets downloaded without any prompt. This will help you to identify the issues with automation.

I tried setting these preferences in my firefox, but it still prompts download window. I can download without prompt only after checking "Do this automatically for files like this from now on" which updates `mimeTypes.rdf` file in the profile directory. So to make this work through automation, you may need to bundle a custom firefox profile that includes a `mimeTypes.rdf` with your TestSuite.

Here's the code to create FirefoxProfile from a given profile directory:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("<PATH_TO_FIREFOX_PROFILE_DIRECTORY_THAT_WORKS_WHEN_TESTED_MANUALLY>");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: I tried changing about:config. But when I configure for the same in other PC. it would be difficult to run the script. Also, I tried setting all preferences as in the link provided by you. The content-type is "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" for the file thats being downloaded in my website.  The issue is due to the new tab getting opened and the new tab doesn't have the preference set.

Comment: I've updated my answer suggesting you to bundle a profile directory along with TestSuite so that it works the same everywhere.